# How to make a programmable pipeline OpenGL context in Racket

Tags: opengl, graphics, racket

In Racket, I'd like to get an OpenGL context from the GUI, clear it to black, and display it to the screen. I'm using the `opengl` library to let me use the variable function pipeline. I presently have the following code:

```
#lang racket/gui
(require opengl)

(define video-canvas%
  (class canvas%
    (init-field width height)
    (super-new [style '(gl no-autoclear)]
               [min-width width]
               [min-height height]
               [stretchable-width #f]
               [stretchable-height #f])

    (send this with-gl-context
          (λ ()
            (glViewport 0 0 width height)
            (glClearColor 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0)))

    (define/public (draw-frame)
        (send this with-gl-context
              (λ () (glClear GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)))
        (send this swap-gl-buffers))))

(define f (new frame% [label "test video"]))
(define vc (new video-canvas% [parent f]
                [width 640] [height 480]))
(send f show #t)
(send vc draw-frame)
```

This would appear to create a frame, place a OpenGL viewport on top of it, and then render it after clearing it to black. However, on my machine, it actually produces:

[image: broken viewport]

This is the default background, not the solid black window I was expecting. I'm running this program on Windows 10 on a computer using Intel HD 520 graphics.

Comment: Anything change if you pass `1.0` into the alpha argument of `glClearColor()`?

Comment: @genpfault Not on the system I originally reported it on. When running with a NVidia GPU, it works with a 1.0 alpha value but not on the Intel graphics hardware.